# Python Password Contain Slash Character

Tags: python

I am using the below details as credentials :

```
"ldap_bind_user": "homeoffice\\myuser",
"ldap_bind_password":"password\Y!"
```

It's giving me `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Invalid \escape: line 16 column 26 (char 579)`

In password `\` character is present so that's why it's throwing me this error. How to pass the password correctly in this case ?

Comment: Double slash \\?

Comment: Password is not working in that case

Comment: `"password\Y!"` -> `r"password\Y!"`

Comment: If this is part of json, it should be `"password\\Y!"`

Answer (score 0):

Try to assign it into variable and pass the variable:
**pass01** = "password\Y!"

than pass to Jason:  "ldap_bind_password": **pass01**

Answer (score 0):

Use a **raw string** by putting `r` in front of the quotes:

```py
"ldap_bind_password": r"password\Y!"
```

Read the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals)